# Delay part of the funcion execution JavaScript and exit function

Tags: javascript, function, timer, delay, exit

So I am making a program for a restaurant. When a table is clicked it is marked as "Paying", and when it's clicked again you are marking it as "leaving the restaurant". What I need is to set an interval until the leaving table is deleted just in case you missclick the table. So the idea is that when you click a "Paying" table to mark it as "leaving" it gets grey coloured for 10 seconds until it is removed from the view, but if you click again the grey table then you can restore that table in case you missclicked it.

The problem I am having is that when I restore the "leaving" table, it gets deleted in 10 seconds anyways the colour and state has changed and I want to cancel the following operations if the "leaving" table is restored. Here you have the code I am using.

Notice that the function to mark it as "leaving" is called moveToFinished(orderId). And the ones that are marked as "Paying" are yellow coloured.

```js
function moveToFinished(orderId) {
    var id = "btn"+orderId;
if (document.contains(document.getElementById(id))) {
    var btn = document.getElementById(id);
    btn.classList.remove("yellow");
    btn.classList.add("grey");
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    /*Here if it is clicked to restore it, I want this funcion to end right
      after calling updateStatusToPaying(orderId);*/
      updateStatusToPaying(orderId);
      return;
    });

    setTimeout(function(){ 
    /*Otherwise, in 10 seconds I want to execute this, so the table is 
      removed.*/
            console.log("10 seconds until " + id + " is deleted.")
            document.getElementById("tableNumbersDiv").removeChild(btn);
    }, 10000);    
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the timeout ID returned by `setTimeout` and use that to cancel the timeout.

```
function moveToFinished(orderId) {
    var id = "btn" + orderId;

    if (document.contains(document.getElementById(id))) {
        var btn = document.getElementById(id);
        btn.classList.remove("yellow");
        btn.classList.add("grey");
        btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
            /*Here if it is clicked to restore it, I want this funcion to end right
            after calling updateStatusToPaying(orderId);*/
            if (window.isRemoving) {
                clearTimeout(window.isRemoving);
            }
            updateStatusToPaying(orderId);
            return;
        });

        window.isRemoving = setTimeout(function(){ 
            /*Otherwise, in 10 seconds I want to execute this, so the table is 
            removed.*/
            console.log("10 seconds until " + id + " is deleted.")
            document.getElementById("tableNumbersDiv").removeChild(btn);
        }, 10000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the setTimeout to a variable and then after the user revert the table - use the clearTimeout global function with your variable as a parameter:

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){}, 10000);
clearTimeout(timeout);
```